# Termux repository has no longer Release file

Tags: termux

I was trying to run the command:

```
pkg install imagemagick
```

And getting an error message:

> The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/termux/termux-packages-24
>   stable Release' does no longer have a Release file. Updating from such
>   a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details.

Comment: It seems that the bintray repository doesn't give access to the hosted files anymore. Trying to download one of the .deb files manually results in 403 (forbidden). The error message you get is probably caused by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package repository is currently offline due to exceeding the bandwidth quota on Bintray. We have asked for it to be re-renabled, and it should hopefully come online within a day.

You can track the progress at:
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/4358